# How to prove the uniqueness of probability measure

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory

Probability essentials P-21

**Theorem 4.1**

(b) Let $(p_\omega)_{\omega \in \Omega}$ be a family of real numbers indexed by the finite or countable set $\Omega$. Then there exists a unique probability $P$ such that $$P(\{\omega\}) = p_\omega$$
if and only if $p_\omega \geq 0$ and  $$\sum_{\omega\in\Omega} p_\omega=1$$

Note: $p_\omega$ is atom.

Question: How to prove the uniqueness of $P$?

Comment: Is $P$ a probability on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$ where $\mathcal{F} \subseteq 2^{\Omega}$?

Answer (score 1):

**Short Answer:** Sigma Additivity

**Explicitly:**
Suppose there is another measure $Q$ such that $Q(\{\omega\})=p_{\omega}$ for all $\omega\in \Omega$ but $P\neq Q$.

Therefore there is a subset $A\subset \Omega$ such that
$$P(A)\neq Q(A)\Rightarrow P(A)-Q(A)\neq 0.$$
Note that $A$ must be countable as a subset of a countable set. Hence the above above may be written as:
$$\begin{align}
P\left(\bigcup_{a\in A}\{a\}\right)-Q\left(\bigcup_{a\in A}\{a\}\right)&\neq0
\\ \underset{\sigma\text{-add.}}{\Rightarrow} \sum_{a\in A}\left(P(\{a\})-Q(\{a\})\right)&\neq 0.
\end{align}$$ 
However $a\in\Omega$ hence $Q(\{a\})=p_a$ and we have
$$\sum_{a\in A}(p_a-p_a)=\sum_{a\in A}(0)=0\neq 0,$$
a contradiction. Hence $Q=P$.